# React Bootstrap table with ajax data

Tags: javascript, jquery, react-bootstrap

I'm using react-bootstrap-table to show some data, and the data is come from a ajax result.

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        data:[]
    };
}
componentDidMount() {
    this.loadData()
}

loadData() {
    $.ajax({
          url: 'url',
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function(data) {
              this.setState({data: data});
          }.bind(this)
        });
}
render() {
    return (
      <BootstrapTable data={this.state.data}>
          <TableHeaderColumn dataField="status">STATUS</TableHeaderColumn>
          <TableHeaderColumn dataField="title" isKey={true}>TITLE</TableHeaderColumn>
          <TableHeaderColumn dataField="type">TYPE</TableHeaderColumn>
          <TableHeaderColumn dataField="start">test</TableHeaderColumn>
          <TableHeaderColumn dataField="end">END</TableHeaderColumn>
          <TableHeaderColumn dataField="days used">DAYS USED</TableHeaderColumn>
      </BootstrapTable>
    );
}
```

This will not work, but if I put some real data to it, then it will work, like this:

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      data:[{id:1,name:"name"}]
    };
  }
```

It seems that bootstrap table need to have non-empty data to get it work. So how to make the table to wait ajax to complete then grab the data?

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do in these cases:

```
render() {
  if(this.state.data.length == 0) { return null; }

  return(
    <BootstrapTable data={this.state.data}>
        <TableHeaderColumn dataField="status">STATUS</TableHeaderColumn>
        <TableHeaderColumn dataField="title" isKey={true}>TITLE</TableHeaderColumn>
        <TableHeaderColumn dataField="type">TYPE</TableHeaderColumn>
        <TableHeaderColumn dataField="start">test</TableHeaderColumn>
        <TableHeaderColumn dataField="end">END</TableHeaderColumn>
        <TableHeaderColumn dataField="days used">DAYS USED</TableHeaderColumn>
    </BootstrapTable>
  )
}
```

This will mean that an empty element will be returned initially, and the table will only be rendered once the AJAX call completes.

Release note documenting this feature is [HERE](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2014/07/17/react-v0.11.html#rendering-to-null).

Answer (score 0):

**Try like this in render() ,**

```
if(this.state.data!= undefined && this.state.data.length > 0) {
return (
<div className = 'container'>
<BootstrapTable data={this.state.data} condensed={true}>
.
.
.
</BootstrapTable>
</div>
);
}else{
return(
<p>No Data!</p>
);
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?